# Turn off screen updating and turn it back on if it were on to start with?

Tags: c#, excel

When running procedures that use Excel, I typically turn some application settings off at the start of the procedure, and then turn them on again at the end of the procedure.

Code for turning application settings off and on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XLTimeTracker
{
    class API
    {
        public static void TurnAppSettingsOff()
        {
            AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.EnableEvents = false;
            AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
        }

        public static void TurnAppSettingsOn()
        {
            if (AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp == null) return;

            AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.EnableEvents = true;
            AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I call this procedures in the following manner:

```
API.TurnAppSettingsOff();
// my code
API.TurnAppSettingsOn();
```

This works well.

**But say that I only want to turn on the app settings that were on before I ran `API.TurnAppSettingsOff()`. What would be a good way to code this?**

Some thoughts:

- I guess I would need to save the previous state of the application settings somehow. For example by writing:

Boolean screenUpdating = AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating;

- I would like the end result to be correct even if a function that turns appsettings off and on also calls another function that turns app settings off and on.
- I don't know if it is best to set all settings using one command such as `API.TurnAppSettingsOff()` or if it would be wiser to user `API.TurnScreenUpdatingOff()` and `API.TurnEventsOff()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just whip up an internal manager class that handles the whole thing similar to the following:

```
public sealed class ApplicationSettingsManager
{
    readonly object app;
    readonly Dictionary<string, object> appSettings;

    public ApplicationSettingsManager(object app)
    {
        this.app = app;
        appSettings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public object Application { get { return app; } }

    public void SaveSetting(string settingName)
    {
        var propInfo = app.GetType().GetProperty(settingName);
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified name is not a valid storable setting.", "setting");

        var value = propInfo.GetValue(app);

        if (appSettings.ContainsKey(settingName))
        {
            appSettings[settingName] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            appSettings.Add(settingName, value);
        }
    }

    public void SaveAllSettings()
    {
        var properties = app.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite &&
                                                             p.CanRead &&
                                                             p.SetMethod.IsPublic &&
                                                             p.GetMethod.IsPublic);

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            var value = p.GetValue(app);

            if (appSettings.ContainsKey(p.Name))
            {
                appSettings[p.Name] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                appSettings.Add(p.Name, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RestoreSetting(string settingName)
    {
        if (!appSettings.ContainsKey(settingName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified name does not correspond to a valid stored setting.", "settingName");

        var propInfo = app.GetType().GetProperty(settingName);
        propInfo.SetValue(app, appSettings[settingName]);
    }

    public void RestoreAllSettingas()
    {
        foreach (var p in appSettings)
        {
            RestoreSetting(p.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick. You would use it as follows;

```
var excelSettingsManager = new ApplicationSettingsManager(AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp);

//store all settings you are going to tamper with...
excelSettingsManager.SaveSetting("EnableEvents");
excelSettingsManager.SaveSetting("ScreenUpdating");

//change excel setting and do your thing...
//...
//when done, restore settings

excelSettingsManager.RestoreAllSettings();
```

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution that I have come up with to solve the problem. It seems simpler to me than the other suggested solutions. Let me know if you think that you have a better solution!

(My code below happens to be in VB.NET)

Class to handle the changing of settings and storing of original state:

```
Public Class ApplicationSettings
    Implements IDisposable
    Private ScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Private Events As Boolean
    Private Production As Boolean = True

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        ScreenUpdating = AddinModule.ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating
        Events = AddinModule.ExcelApp.EnableEvents
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        AddinModule.ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
        AddinModule.ExcelApp.EnableEvents = Events
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is how I use it in code:

```
Private Sub AdxRibbonButton1_OnClick(sender As Object, control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean) Handles AdxRibbonButton1.OnClick
    Using New ApplicationSettings
        'My code
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) class to implement a last-in-first-out (LIFO) behavior.

```
struct ExcelEventSettings
{
    public bool EnableEvents;
    public bool ScreenUpdating;
}

class Example
{
    private Stack<ExcelEventSettings> settingStack = new Stack<ExcelEventSettings>();

    // you can call this function as often as you called SaveAppSettings
    public void RestoreAppSettings()
    {
        if (settingStack.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("There is no previous state!");

        ExcelEventSettings prevState = settingStack.Pop();

        setCurrentEnableEvents(prevState.EnableEvents);
        setCurrentScreenUpdating(prevState.ScreenUpdating);
    }

    public void SetAppSettings(bool enableEvents, bool screenUpdating)
    {
        ExcelEventSettings currentState;

        currentState.EnableEvents = getCurrentEnableEvents();
        currentState.ScreenUpdating = getCurrentScreenUpdating();

        settingStack.Push(currentState);

        setCurrentScreenUpdating(enableEvents);
        setCurrentEnableEvents(screenUpdating);
    }

    private bool getCurrentEnableEvents()
    {
       // Here you would call your Excel function
    }

    private bool getCurrentScreenUpdating()
    {
       // Here you would call your Excel function
    }

    private void setCurrentEnableEvents(bool value)
    {
        // Here you would call your Excel function
    }

    private void setCurrentScreenUpdating(bool value)
    {
        // Here you would call your Excel function
    }
}
```

Comment: Without an explanation as to how the op can use this, this is nothing more than a comment.

Comment: I am preparing an example just in these moments.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use an integer to represent the state, and hide it using a boolean. This is what I mean:

```
this.Working = true;

try
{
    // do something
}
finally
{
    this.Working = false;
}
```

Then implement the `Working` property like this:

```
private int working;
public bool Working
{
    get { return working > 0; }
    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
             working++;
        }
        else
        {
             working--;
        }
    }
}
```

Internally it just remembers how much times working as been set, using that integer. If `working` is `0`, then you are back to normal.

You can set `Working` as much times as you want. As long it is `> 0` it will return `true`. Don't forget to wrap your code into a `try...catch` or you will lose count.

You can do the API call if `Working` is set to `false`. Then set it to `true`:

```
if (!this.Working)
{
    // do API call
    this.TurnAppSettingsOff();
}

this.Working = true;

try
{
    // do something
}
finally
{
    this.Working = false;
}

if (!this.Working)
{
    // do reset API call
    this.TurnAppSettingsOn();
}
```